# How to deal with an object that might be a $q promise in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, promise

In cases where a function may either return a value directly, or a $q.promise, what's the best way to handle that value? Is there a way to check weather an object is a `$q.defer().promise`, or is there an other way to deal with such an uncertainty?

Comment: check its constructor or a unique property.

Comment: $q.when is exactly what you need

Comment: You can always return the promise but as calebboyd says use $q.when if you are unsure of the type and not in control of the code providing you the return result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$q.when(value).then(...)`

`$q.when` takes any value. If the value is not a promise, it's wrapped as a promise and resolved immediately, else, it's just returned. From [Angular's q implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L421):

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party)
>   then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are
>   dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the
>   promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> @param {*} value Value or a promise @returns {Promise} Returns a
>   promise of the passed value or promise